# C++ initialize map of pairs

Tags: c++, stl, initialization

I want to statically initialize a `map<string, pair<some_enum, string> >`. Let's say a map from employee id to job title (enum) + name.

I would love for it to look like this:

```
map<string, pair<some_enum, string> > = {
  { "1234a", { BOSS, "Alice" }},
  { "5678b", { SLAVE, "Bob" }},
  { "1111b", { IT_GUY, "Cathy" }},
};
```

What is the best way to do this in C++?

Comment: The best way is how you have it. I also like how you have it sorted by job title.

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/Jzvi1f). What seem to be the problem?

Comment: This should work if you use a compiler compatible with C++11 standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++11, what you have works fine (assuming you add an identifier name to the variable declaration).

In versions prior, one approach would be to have a free function that builds the map:

```
typedef std::map<std::string, std::pair<some_enum, std::string> > map_type;

static map_type create_map()
{
    map_type map;

    map["1234a"] = std::make_pair(BOSS, "Alice");
    map["5678b"] = std::make_pair(SLAVE, "Bob");
    map["1111b"] = std::make_pair(IT_GUY, "Cathy");

    return map;
}

map_type foo = create_map();
```

Or you can make use of [Boost.Assign](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html):

```
std::map<std::string, std::pair<some_enum, std::string> > foo =
    boost::assign::map_list_of("1234a", std::make_pair(BOSS, "Alice"))
                              ("5678b", std::make_pair(SLAVE, "Bob"))
                              ("1111b", std::make_pair(IT_GUY, "Cathy"));
```

Comment: (missing brackets after make_pair)

Comment: @PiotrS. They are not required; the compiler will infer the template type arguments.  (That's the whole reason for `std::make_pair` -- if you were going to specify the template type arguments yourself you could just use the `std::pair` constructor directly.)

Comment: I meant () brackets, not <>

Comment: @PiotrS. Ah, you meant parens.  Good catch, I will fix that.

Comment: If there's one thing I've learned from SO, it's to never say brackets and expect people to know which kind you're talking about.

Answer (score 8):

The best way in C++11:

```
std::map<string, pair<some_enum, std::string>> my_map = {
  { "1234a", { BOSS, "Alice" }},
  { "5678b", { SLAVE, "Bob" }},
  { "1111b", { IT_GUY, "Cathy" }},
};
```

It's that easy.

It's not possible at all in standard C++03 without using external libraries like boost.

Comment: C++03 isn't *too* bad. Something like `boost::whatever_map_list_of("1234a", std::make_pair(BOSS, "Alice"))("5678b", …)`

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking about standard C++. I'll let other talk about boost, because I don't have much experience with it.